# USB speakers are not listed neither in the audio device list not in the Playback devices list

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, speakers, logitech-speakers

Therefore, I cannot select the USB speakers as an audio output. These speakers are not listed in the Playback device list from the audio icon in the task bar.

See pictures below

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXBO0.png)

[Sound icon in task bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QCt4.png)

This is the config in device manager:

Not listed in the Audio inputs and outputs

[Device manager 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nG5S.png)
But it is listed in the Sound, video and game controllers (Logitech USB Speaker)

[Device manager 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRISA.png)

This is a [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/1629496/usb-speakers-correctly-identified-in-device-manager-in-windows-10-not-showing-u), where everything was checked.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I was using already an older version of the Realtek driver. I had 6.0.9075.1, and then I installed the 6.0.9163.1 from the Dell website. Furthermore, I restarted the laptop, and it works finally.

[Here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/usb-speakers-are-not-listed-neither-in-the-audio/cd9d1729-ab7f-4246-a09b-02a53f14c5ce?auth=1) are other suggestions I received from the microft support page.